# how to save the text entered in a form (EXTJS)?

Tags: extjs

How to save the data which entered in the textfields of the form,when i click on the submit button ?

Comment: at the respective url location

Comment: And what do you have behind that url? Some kind of framework? PHP? You need to give us more information about your system setup before we can give any kind of meaningful advice.

Comment: yes by submitting the form.but i'm getting the error as 'access is denied' in 'ext-base.js' file.

Answer (score 0):

When defining your form use the `url` to specify your url to which the form data has to be submitted.

Then you can submit the form using the following code:

```
var form = formPanel.getForm();
form.submit({
    success: function(form,action) {
        //success
    },
    failure: function(form,action) {
        //fail
    }
});
```

Comment: i did this coding part but getting error as  'access is denied' in 'ext-base.js' file.

Comment: Are you submitting to the same domain? Ajax requests are limited by the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)